# Adding touch-area to UIView (iOS5)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a MainView with MainViewController. Now I want to add a specific area where I want to register touches (painting in a specific area). How could I do this? 
I thought about adding a sub-view with its own sub-viewcontroller, but [this guy](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) tells this is not a good approach.

Comment: Can't you just add a custom subview ?

Comment: But then how could I restrict touch events only to this subview?

Comment: By testing coordinates, wether they're well inside its frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom view as a property, called touchArea

```
-(void) touchesBegan/Moved/Ended (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchArea.frame, location))
//code
}

}
```

Comment: looks promissing, but it seems that the coordinates of the location/custom view are shifted.

Comment: this is how I use it in my app and did not have any problems so far, every touch gets in perfectly.Of course, you'd still have to think of global coordinates (of the main VC) if you're going to do specific actions that depend on the location. If your logic mostly depends on what happens on the custom view, then I think UIViewController containment (as Ole Begemann mentioned) might be better for you.

Answer (score 2):

The post you linked to is partially out of date because it was written before Apple introduced support for [View Controller Containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW16) in iOS 5.

That said, it's your choice whether:

1. the subview is managed by its own view controller or
2. you use the `MainViewController` directly to respond to touches in the subview or
3. you create a `UIView` subclass that interprets touches on itself without the help of a view controller.

Comment: yes, found that out, too. thank you! as new as I am to objective-c I still need a kick in the bud here... :-/ so what dou you think would be the best approach? any kick-off-links you would share?

Comment: would have marked you both as answer. chose Kaan because he has less points that you. but thank you very much - good answer!